# ES6 fetch error 400 - Invalid Request

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, fetch

I am developing a reactjs app that calls an external REST service. The problem is that fetch returns "400 Invalid request" as if body is invalid, but it isn't.

```
const sub=(store,rulesMap,values) =>{
  const buffer=packer.pack(rulesMap,values);
  const body=prepareBody(buffer,rulesMap);
  fetch('http://STMIVAPIGTW01.si.it:8080/ip-engine/pay',
    {
        mode:'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method:'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.ok)
            return response.json();
        else
            return response.text();
    })
    .catch(error => window.alert('Error:'+ error))
    .then(function(myJson) {
        window.alert(myJson);
    });
}
```

I can't post body because is too long but body got a correct answer by postman.
This is the first time that I use fetch. Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: can you please paste the `body` object ?

Comment: I can't post body because is too long but body got a  correct answer  by postman